# Why do my stream input operations get skipped over?

Tags: c++, iostream

I have this code where in option lists will display when run. my problem is when I enter number 2, the option 2 program doesn't work well. It just go directly to asking the amount paid instead of asking first the cost of purchase.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
float circle (float a)
{
    float z;
    z = 3.141593 * (a * a);
    return (z);
}
float square (float b)
{
    float y;
    y = b * b;
    return (y);
}
float rectangle (float c, float d)
{
    float x;
    x = c * d;
    return (x);
}
float triangle (float e, float f)
{
    float w;
    w = (e * f) / 2;
    return (w);
}
void exit ()
{
    cout << "THANK YOU! GOODBYE!" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    int x;
    do
    {

        cout << "Please choose an option below: \n";
        cout << "1. Area of Shapes\n";
        cout << "2. Cost of your items\n";
        cout << "3. Flood Control\n";
        cout << "4. Fibonacci Numbers\n";
        cout << "5. Addition Table\n";
        cout << "6. Exit\n";
        cin >> x;
        if (x == 1)
        {
            system("cls");
            float n;
            float l;
            float m;
            float radius;
            float side;
            float length;
            float width;
            float base;
            float height;

            do
            {
                cout << "1 => Area of Circle" << endl;
                cout << "2 => Area of Square" << endl;
                cout << "3 => Area of Rectangle" << endl;
                cout << "4 => Area of Trian1gle" << endl;
                cout << "5 => Return to Main Menu" << endl;
                cout << "0 => Exit" << endl;
                cout << "Please enter number of your choice: ";
                cin >> n;
                system("cls");
                {
                    if (n == 0)
                    {
                        exit ();
                        system("pause");
                        return 0;
                    }
                    else if (n == 1)
                    {
                        cout << "Enter radius of the circle: ";
                        cin >> radius;
                        l = circle (radius);
                        cout << "Area of the circle is: " << l << endl;
                        system("pause");
                        system("cls");
                    }
                    else if (n == 2)
                    {
                        cout << "Enter side of the square: ";
                        cin >> side;
                        cout << "Area of the square is: " << square (side) << endl;
                        system("pause");
                        system("cls");
                    }
                    else if (n == 3)
                    {
                        cout << "Enter length of the rectangle: ";
                        cin >> length;
                        cout << "Enter width of the rectangle: ";
                        cin >> width;
                        m = rectangle (length, width);
                        cout << "Area of the rectangle is: " << m << endl;
                        system("pause");
                        system("cls");
                    }
                    else if (n == 4)
                    {
                        cout << "Enter base of the triangle: ";
                        cin >> base;
                        cout << "Enter height of the triangle: ";
                        cin >> height;
                        cout << "Area of the triangle is: " << triangle (base, height) << endl;
                        system("pause");
                        system("cls");
                    }
                    else if (n == 5)
                    {
                        exit ();
                    }
                    else
                        cout << "Invalid number. Please enter a valid number below" << endl;
                }
            }
            while (n != 0 && n != 5);
            cout << endl << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
        }

        else if (x == 2)
        {
            system("cls");
            string mystr;
            float cost = 0;
            float amount = 0;
            float total;

            cout << "Total Cost: P";
            getline (cin, mystr);
            stringstream(mystr) >> cost;
            cout << endl;
            total = cost * .06;
            cout << "Sales Tax Value: P" << total << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Cost of Item: P" << cost + total << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Amount Paid: P";
            getline (cin, mystr);
            stringstream(mystr) >> amount;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Total Amount Purchased: P" << cost << endl;
            cout << "Sales Tax Value: P" << total << endl;
            cout << "Total Amount + Sales Tax: P" << cost + total << endl;
            cout << "Total Amount Paid: P" << amount << endl;
            cout << "Change: P" << amount - (cost + total) << endl;
            system("pause");
            cout << endl;
            cout << "THANK YOU! ENJOY YOUR MEAL!" << endl;


            system("pause");
            system("cls");
        }
        else if (x > 6)
            cout << "Invalid Input";
        else
        {
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    while (x != 6);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

For the posters education

You do

```
switch (n) {

  case 1:
    //... Code for n == 1  - If long put into another function. If using local variables put code bloc in braces
    break;
  case 2:
   // Diitto for n==2

  default: // No match
    // All other values of n not listed above
}
```

Comment: So what does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: at first I enter an option. option 1 is already working. option 2 is where i have problems. when i enter number 2 and click enter it displays the total cost up to the cost of item. it should be asking  the user the total cost and once entered it will do the computations and display the amount paid.

Comment: i tried to debug my project and it says cost = ? and also cin = ?

Comment: Have you hear of `switch`?

Comment: i've read it but haven't used it. don't know how it works

Comment: @Crazy1923 - It would make the code easier to read

Comment: @EdHeal i'm trying it now but having an error jump to case label

Comment: @Crazy1923 - I add an edit to you post - easier to read

Comment: @EdHeal - I've tried using the switch to the program but when i enter the value of x it doesn't do anything. it just redisplay the main options.

Comment: @Crazy1923 - The bit after **EDIT**

Comment: @EdHeal - i have the problem in the second option.

Comment: In what way - just put in the code after the if statement

Comment: i've already done it but an error in compiling. i'd enclosed then the program in after each case but it only redisplays the main menu

Comment: @Crazy1923 - the switch is a programming improvement - not the answer but that is given below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What went wrong

Say you type your menu selection:

```
2<Enter>
```

Then the content of the `std::cin` stream will be:

```
2\n
```

When your menu selection runs...

```
cin >> x;
```

...it reads a number off the line but doesn't consume any trailing whitespace nor the newline, so the remaining state content could be denoted like this:

```
\n
```

Then your code for menu option 2 starts running:

```
        cout << "Total Cost: P";
        getline (cin, mystr);
```

...the `getline` looks at `std::cin` and finds the left over `\n` mentioned above, and says "hey, an empty line - I'll set `mystr` to an empty string".  Notice that it did *not* do what you'd hoped: namely wait for you to type some more input and read *that* into `mystr`.

### How to fix it

Before calling `getline(cin, mystr)` you want to remove the left-over `\n` typed when entering the menu selection.  The code changes for that (adding error handling too):

```
#include <limits>

...
        cout << "Total Cost: P";
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        if (!std::getline(std::cin, mystr))
        {
            std::cerr << "unable to read mystr\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        std::istringstream iss(mystr);
        iss >> cost;
        if (!iss)
        {
             std::cerr << "mystr doesn't contain a valid cost number\n";
             exit(1);
        }
```

### How you could have found the problem

When you get stuck like this, try adding some "trace" statements to print out the values of variables and find where they differ from your expectation... that can at least give you a better idea how to isolate and describe the problem, and what to google for to fix it.

```
std::out << "mystr '" << mystr << "'\n";`
```

Try to use error handling like I've illustrated so the program stops (or prompts for better input) when there's a problem parsing the user's input.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what you mean. I'm only a student. Please explain in detailed. thanks

Comment: @Crazy1923 fair enough - I've edited my answer to make it much "gentler" - hopefully will help you more.  Cheers.